# Is it possible to make Either-type from TypeScript generic spread or array types?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function with rest parameters, with different types:

```
function a<T extends any[]>(...opts: T){
}
```

I need to declare return-type of function like this:

```
a(100, "Hello") => number | string;
```

Another example with array:

```
type B<T extends any[]> = `one of type of element T`
```

I know a non-universal way with multiple generics:

```
type B<T1, T2, T3> = T1 | T2 | T3;
```

But, maybe, there is some universal way? Is it possible?

P.S. The same question about `&` operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type query to get the item of an element of the array:

```
function a<T extends any[]>(...opts: T): T[number]{
    return opts[0]
}
a(100, "Hello") // => number | string;
```

Comment: @arvitaly You can index into `T` using any `number` .. so `T[number]` will be the result of such an operation. Generally you can index into a type using one of it's properties. For example `Person['name']` will result in the type of the `name` property of `Person` (assuming `Person` has one). Or `Person[keyof Person]` will result in a union of all property types of `Person`. Read more about type queries here:https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you, very much.